# c# BasicAWSCredentials object does not have SecureString parameter for SecretKey

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, securestring

According to the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_Runtime_BasicAWSCredentials.htm

The BasicAWSCredentials class accepts SecureString for the SecretKey. This is good, because for my application I've stored a SecretKey somewhere using SecureString. However in my C# application, I have no option to instantiate this class with the SecureString parameter. My only options are String, String (AccessKey, SecretKey). This means I have to convert SecureString to String in my code, which defeats the purpose of using SecureString in the first place as far as my basic understanding goes.

When I look in Visual Studio, there are no overrides for the BasicAWSCredentials class. What am I missing here?

[image]

I'm using .NET 4 Client Profile (for infrastructure reasons) and AWSSDK.Core 3.3.24.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at documentation for an old version of the AWSSDK. It says it's for version 1.5.x from 2014. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/ instead.

Just did a quick search for SecureString on the site and saw this in one of the [old migration documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/migration-v2-net-sdk.html) (v1-v2):

> Removal of SecureString
>
> The use of System.Security.SecureString was
> removed in version 2 of the SDK because it is not available on the
> WinRT and Windows Phone 8 platforms.

Comment: Ah great. Well that's a bummer. I don't suppose you have any tips as to how to deal with this scenario, I don't want to be decrypting the securestring in memory to string first, as it leaves it wide open to someone getting the plain text string from in-memory.

Comment: @JamesMatson maybe use the old version for .NET Framework, provided you read through the changelog and have made sure there aren’t any major security issues. SecureStrings are removed from .NET Core because it doesn’t quite improve security outside of the .NET Framework. https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

Comment: Thanks Tyress. I am a competent application developer but am struggling with the security side of things. I am storing some AWS credentials on a machine which is physical and outside of the AWS cloud. I am trying to find a simple way to protect those keys in the app.config for the application. Secure String offers at least a way to protect it at rest from non-technical people who might find the file, but I know i need something better longer term. I don't suppose you would be open to offering some advice via PM or email if you happen to have some ideas in this space? No pressure of course :)

Comment: @JamesMatson I can contribute and have a bit of experience but I don't know all of the possible attacks you can get nowadays, so you will definitely save more time asking someone with a more security-focused background. All I can say is SecureString is to prevent more high-level attacks, but if it's in a file it's up for grabs for anyone. Take a look at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html . Good luck! :)